# Is it valid to access global variables in R function and how to assign it in a package?

Tags: r, package

I have a package which provides a script and some functions. Within the script I assign a variable which will be used by the function. This works if the function gets executed within the script but might fail if I just call the function since the variable doesn't exist.

If I use `devtools::check()` I get warnings, that the variable within the function isn't defined. How can I handle this properly?

### Edit

I am thinking about to use `get()` within the function to assign the variable within the function to get rid of this warnings. So the question is, is `myp2` the correct way of doing something like this? Maybe some `trycatch` to handle errors?

```
ab <- c(1,2,3)

myp1 <- function() {
  print(ab)
  return(1)
}

myp2 <- function() {
  ab <- get('ab')
  print(ab)
  return(1)
}

myp1()
myp2()
```

Comment: Using global variables in a package is definitely bad practice. I'd suggest to exclude the script from the package and make your functions explicitly dependent on the object.

Comment: Actually, the functions are not exported... Using a package is more the way to develop, document and "package" the whole thing. The function might not be useful for anything else at all. Thats why everything is together.

Comment: In my opinion, it's bad practice to have functions that rely on global objects, and you get the warnings precisely for that reason. If you just are looking for a way to trick the check and not getting warnings, your `get` solution might work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
if(!exists("your variable")){
stop("You have not defined your variable")}
```

This would check to see if what you are looking for exists. A better practice would be to define the variable in the function and have the default value be the name of the thing for which you are looking.

Comment: I would still get the warning on `devtools::check()` because `your variable` still isn't assigned within the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
myp <- function(x) {
  print(x)
  return(1)
}

ab <- c(1,2,3)

myp(x = ab)
```

If possible, it would be also better to substitute the script with a function.